# how to install torch on armv7l on raspberry pi 4

Tags: pytorch, torch, raspberry-pi4, armv7, torchvision

I can't install any torch version on rasp 4 armv7l. i tried to build it from whl, but that does not work either.(maybe someone knows a working source?)

Any help is appreciated!

i have tried pip, conda, conda-forge, building it from scratch, but none seems to work. I could not find a tutorial on the web either.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to install torch on my rpi 4 armv7l. There are whl files you can find online but it depends on which version of torch you like to install.

For a step-by-step guide on how to install once you have the whl file, you can check out: https://medium.com/secure-and-private-ai-writing-challenge/a-step-by-step-guide-to-installing-pytorch-in-raspberry-pi-a1491bb80531

For the whl files you can check out these GitHub pages:

https://github.com/Kashu7100/pytorch-armv7l
https://github.com/nmilosev/pytorch-arm-builds